# Can't put offline disk 0 on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, powershell

I'm trying to boot and run the physical installation of Debian in Virtualbox on Windows 10. Since virtualbox gives to me this error :

[image: error]

I thought to put offline the disk 0 where debian is installed but Windows 10 refuses to do that. I tried using the powershell,but it said :

> PS C:\Users\mariuccio> set-disk 0 -isOffline $true
>
> set-disk : Operation not supported on a critical disk.
>
> Activity ID: {de8e4c02-100c-456f-82ec-f346d8454447}
>
> In riga:1 car:1
>
> - set-disk 0 -isOffline $true
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/
>
> Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-Disk],CimException
>
> ```
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 41009,Set-Disk
> ```

and also disk 1 :

> PS C:\Users\mariuccio> set-disk 1 -isOffline $true
>
> set-disk : Operation not supported on a critical disk.
>
> Activity ID: {96302326-44ea-4283-a42b-c7f6537d3725}
>
> In riga:1 car:1
>
> - set-disk 0 -isOffline $true
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/
>
> Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-Disk],CimException
>
> ```
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 41009,Set-Disk
> ```

This is the structure of the disks :

[image: disks structure]

On the partition of 103,51 GB of the disk 0 there is the installation of Debian and on the 4,41 GB there is the swap partition...I've disabled the paging file on all drives...what do you suggest to me to do ? thanks.

Comment: check here : https://ibb.co/n5CNFk ; https://ibb.co/jaLngQ

Comment: I'm trying to run a physical installation of Debian in VirtualBox on Windows 10.

Comment: Do you run VirtualBox with admin rights?

Comment: ...........yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this in powershell and ensure it doesn't report that there is a pagefile there:

```
get-ciminstance -classname win32_pagefileusage
```

If that doesn't work, try unmounting D: first and then take it offline (right click the D: and click "Change Drive letters and paths" and just remove the drive letter). You can always put it back.

Be sure to restart as well.

---------Update 6/7/17--------

Also try starting Windows in 'safe mode with networking' and see if it will let you unmount the drive then.

Comment: Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti sono riservati.

PS C:\Users\mariuccio> get-ciminstance -classname win32_pagefileusage
PS C:\Users\mariuccio> no error.

Comment: Are you running programs from the D:? You posted a screenshot of virtualbox, is there a machine running that uses the D: as a storage location?

Comment: Windows said that the drive D was used,I don't know why,but anyway I have been able to unmount it. And then I tried to put offline the whole disk 0. But Windows refuses to do that. it says again : "set-disk : Operation not supported on a critical disk"

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? Try starting windows in "safe mode with networking" and see if you can unmount it then.

Comment: I started windows in safe mode with networking,but the disk cannot yet be put offline.