# I want to put offline disk 0 on windows 10 because I want boot a physical installation of Linux through the Hyper-V but Windows refuses to do that

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, hyper-v

I have dual boot Win10 & Debian on my PC. I want to boot the Debian inside Win10 using Hyper-V. I came across this :

> [Can't put offline disk 0 on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1206675/cant-put-offline-disk-0-on-windows-10)

and this :

> https://superuser.com/a/674714/519592

I read that if I want to use the physical installation of Linux inside the hyper-v,I should put offline the disk 0 where Debian is installed but Windows 10 refuses to do that. This is the structure of the disks of my comp :

[image: pic]

I want to put offline the disk0,because the partition of 103.51 GB contains the Debian installation that I want to boot with the hyper-v.

I tried to do it in several ways :

```
1) Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Mario Zio> set-disk 0 -isOffline $true
set-disk : Operation not supported on a critical disk.
Activity ID: {a7af4f39-1847-4ec4-9c26-85605f61ba5b}
At line:1 char:1
+ set-disk 0 -isOffline $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-Disk], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 41009,Set-Disk
```

2) in `safe mode with networking` : nothing

3) disabling the paging file for the disk 0,but it is not enabled,as you can see here :

[image: 2]

4) Previously I installed the tool `Ext2Mgr system driver for Windows`. I thought that it could keep locked the drive 0,but I removed it and I restarted the comp,but the drive 0 still can't be put offline.

5) other ideas ?

UPDATE :

For an unknown reason,it doesn't work anymore. I've enabled the hyper-v,but it says that the linux virtual machine failed to start. Check the attached screenshots :

1) [image: 1]
2) [image: 2]
3) [image: 3]
4) [image: 4]
5) [image: 5]

Comment: `Dati` on disk 0 is a active system partition, which means it has the Windows Boot Manager that booted the current system on it. You probably have to move it to `C:` (i.e. install a copy with `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C:` and make sure your BIOS(/UEFI) (legacy) boot the disk where `C:` is on)

Comment: fixed with neosmart bcdedit,by installing the Windows boot manager on Disk 1 and removing it from Disk 0. Thanks man.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore. I've updated the question.

Comment: But that's a different issue? Check your BCD for the hypervisor option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution : bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto